# Rest ApiFilters and howto use them

Tags: java, web-services, rest, authentication, servlet-filters

I would like to add some filtering to my requests.

So this is my current code:

```
ServletContextHandler con = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
con.addFilter(AuthApiFilter.class,  "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.INCLUDE,DispatcherType.REQUEST));
handlerList.setHandlers(new Handler[] { con } );
jettyServer.setHandler(handlerList);
```

Note, that not an instance of the Filter is passed to the context instead it is a class.

Now part of my Filter looks like:

```
public class ApiFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    private List<String> apiKeys;

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        //..verifyKey from request with keys in list
```

Question: How can i set the apiKeys when i load them at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial

I suppose you set the API key in your filter configuration via web.xml.

If this is not runtime enough, I would set up a configuration facility in my webapp, providing values for keys (in the simples case a Map in a singleton) and put the key in the web.xml configuration.

Comment: Have a look at the login-servlet in the tutorial, i would have to set values for user and pwd during runtime. web.xml should not be needed. it should be done programmatically.